# Why did Nano explode?

Tags: nichijou

I was recommended *My Ordinary Life* by a friend and have watched the first episode.  Needless to say, I was confused and amazed.

Towards the beginning of the first episode, [Nano](http://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/character.php?id=24037) trips into a guy and results in a rather large explosion.

I have a feeling trying to apply logic to this show is likely impossible, but is there any reason for the explosion?  Was it from tripping, the cherry blossom, or possibly the sandal falling off?

**Note:** I've only seen the first episode so far so (if there even are any) please refrain from spoilers.

Comment: Watch more episodes.  The context, if there is any to be had, will be revealed over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nichijou's characters frequently have over-the-top reactions, this is just another one of those.

Here's a clip from later on that demonstrates my point (out of many) - http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UD95EI3zD8A (no plot spoilers, but don't watch it you want to watch everything chronologically)

Nano's explosion was a purely a manifestation of her fretting and embarrassment, She wasn't actually hurt too badly and appears uninjured in the next scene.

Comment: Dogs are evil :P

Comment: I think I'm gonna start watching the show thanks to all this.

Comment: It's amazing, you should :)

Comment: I can guess what happen by David's comment since I already watch this anime but since the video is blocked, care to explain what happen in that video?

Comment: @Darjeeling If I remember correctly, a dog bites Yuko's hand and her screams become a giant laser that blasts into space.